# Install font batch file and vbscript

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

In batch file script the first below line copies myFont.ttf into Windows font directory, and the second line registers it into Registry.

```
XCOPY "myFont.ttf" "C:\Windows\Fonts"
REG add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts" /v "myFont (TrueType)" /t REG_SZ /d myFont.ttf /f
```

An application sends the WM_FONTCHANGE message to all top-level windows in the system after changing the pool of font resources.

To send this message, call the SendMessage function with the following parameters.

following code is in VB programming language but I need to send WM_FONTCHANGE using  SendMessage function in batch file script or at least vbscript, But I don't know how do it in batch file script, If you know help me please, thanks.

```
Private Const HWND_BROADCAST = &HFFFF&
Private Const WM_FONTCHANGE = &H1D
Private Declare Function AddFontResource Lib "gdi32" Alias "AddFontResourceA" (ByVal lpFileName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim res As Long
    res = AddFontResource("C:\Fonts\Nordic__.ttf")
    If res > 0 Then
        SendMessage HWND_BROADCAST, WM_FONTCHANGE, 0, 0
        MsgBox res & " fonts were added!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code conversion service, where you post code written in one language the desired language you want and we churn out code for you. Where is the code you've written trying to do so in either language, and what **specific** problem have you encountered doing so?

Comment: Neither VBScript nor batch can do what you want.

Comment: [Powershell could do what you want](https://github.com/wormeyman/FindFonts/blob/master/Add-Font.ps1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution, special thank to [JosefZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz), as he said Powershell is the solution, All you need is download and copy [Add-font.ps1](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/deploymentguys/2010/12/04/adding-and-removing-fonts-with-windows-powershell/) by [Michael Murgolo](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/profile/Michael+Murgolo) to your project folder and copy below lines into your batch file:

```
@echo off
PowerShell Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
PowerShell -command "& '%~dp0Add-Font.ps1' -path '%~dp0myFont.ttf'"
```

Note you must run this script as Administrator, hence you need to add %~dp0 before your files.

Thats all, you even don't need the codes in my question, good luck.