# batch file Parse JSON

Tags: json, batch-file

This is my JSON I want to set only "1.1.3" which is version from "stable" object to a variable(without quotes) in a batch file.
I want it dynamic, maybe in future composer changed it into "version": "1.1.3.6" or even "version": "1.1.3-beta2", I want get whatever value of version.

Thank you.

myFile.json

```
{
    "stable": [{"path": "/download/1.1.3/composer.phar", "version": "1.1.3", "min-php": 50300}],
    "preview": [{"path": "/download/1.1.3/composer.phar", "version": "1.1.3", "min-php": 50300}],
    "snapshot": [{"path": "/composer.phar", "version": "334d0cce6b056e7555daf4c68c48cbe40ee4d51a", "min-php": 50300}]
}
```

Comment: Assuming the positions of the fields never change, this is a pretty straightforward `for /f` loop. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yeah but I get it from "http://getcomposer.org/versions" I'm not sure whether they change the positions or not, there is a parser for cmd but I don't know how it works unfortunately, http://stedolan.github.io/jq

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the love of Pete! Use a JSON parser.  The data is already hierarchical.  It's more graceful to objectify it and dig down the hierarchy than to tokenize it and count the lines / words.

```perl
@echo off & setlocal

set "jsonfile=test.json"

set "psCmd="add-type -As System.Web.Extensions;^
$JSON = new-object Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer;^
$JSON.DeserializeObject($input).stable.version""

for /f %%I in ('^<"%jsonfile%" powershell -noprofile %psCmd%') do set "version=%%I"

echo Version: %version%
```

As an added bonus, if you're calling a PowerShell snippet anyway, you can also use `Invoke-WebRequest` to fetch the JSON from the web.

```perl
@echo off & setlocal

set "jsonURL=https://getcomposer.org/versions"

set "psCmd="add-type -As System.Web.Extensions;^
$JSON = new-object Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer;^
$JSON.DeserializeObject((Invoke-WebRequest %jsonURL%).content).stable.version""

for /f %%I in ('powershell -noprofile %psCmd%') do set "version=%%I"

echo Version: %version%
```

---

If you need compatibility with XP / Vista or if you just want a script that runs faster than the PowerShell helper, you can use JScript to achieve the same effect.

```perl
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off & setlocal

set "URL=https://getcomposer.org/versions"

for /f "delims=" %%I in ('cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" "%URL%"') do set "ver=%%I"

echo Version: %ver%

goto :EOF
@end // end Batch / begin JScript hybrid code

var htmlfile = WSH.CreateObject('htmlfile'),
    x = WSH.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

x.open("GET",WSH.Arguments(0),true);
x.setRequestHeader('User-Agent','XMLHTTP/1.0');
x.send('');
while (x.readyState != 4) WSH.Sleep(50);

htmlfile.write('<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" />');
var obj = htmlfile.parentWindow.JSON.parse(x.responseText);
htmlfile.close();

WSH.Echo(obj.stable[0].version);
```

Comment: Thank you [rojo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1683264/rojo) you are awesome, amazing answer!

Comment: Pete and Repete were sitting on a fence.  Pete fell off.  Who was left?

Comment: Repeat. Pete and Repeat were sitting on a fence Pete fell off who was left. On and on it goes.....

Comment: rojo is there any solution for this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38111622/install-font-batch-file-and-vbscript) without using powershell? I only need SendMessage(WM_FONTCHANGE) to inform the system that I just added a font, now I have to use an extra file add-font.ps1 and use powershell.exe :(

Comment: @Amigo Does this work?  `rundll32 user32.dll,SendMessage 0xffff 0x1D`

Comment: rojo I don't get any error but this code doesn't do anything, Why you think?`@echo off
rundll32 Gdi32.dll,AddFontResource %SystemRoot%\Fonts\myFont.ttf
rundll32 user32.dll,SendMessage 0xffff 0x001D,0,0
rundll32 user32.dll,PostMessage 0xffff 0x001D,0,0`

Comment: I already copied myFont.ttf into fonts folder and ran the batch file as administrator but It doesn't work unfortuantely...

Comment: @Amigo I was afraid of that.  I only know of one other hack that might help.  Setting a value with `setx` also triggers a `WM_SETTINGSCHANGE`.  I wonder whether that would also force your windows to reload available fonts?  Try something like `(setx /m foo bar & reg delete "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /f /v foo) >NUL 2>NUL` and see what happens.  If it doesn't work, then a PowerShell or .NET solution would be the only other paths I can think of.

Comment: But how do you get more properties of "stable"? What if I want to get the "path" as well? I can't call $JSON.DesereializeObject again in the script.

Comment: @JakeOPJ One way would be to change the `for...in (cscript...)` line to `for /f "delims=" %%I in ('cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" "%URL%"') do set "%%I"`.  Then any `WSH.Echo` statements in your JScript should be output as `"varname=value"` to be assigned back to the cmd batch runtime.  Example: `for (var i in obj.stable[0]) { WSH.Echo(i + '=' + obj.stable[0][i]); }`

Comment: @rojo - I'm just starting out with scripting, bear with me please. How would I do it in the first case, reading from the json file directly, not from a URL call? I tried lots of workarounds but can't seem to find the proper syntax. Thanks

Comment: @JakeOPJ There are two basic ways.  You could either do it with a `Scripting.FileSystemObject` object, or by redirecting the JSON file into cscript (`cscript ... < jsonfile.json`) then consuming the JSON with `while (WSH.StdIn.ReadLine())`.  The first method is probably more straightforward for a JScript / VBScript rookie.  Google [*reading files with "JScript"*](https://google.com/?q=read+files+with+%22JScript%22) (the quotes should require JScript and exclude JavaScript).  If you get stuck, create a new question post tagged JScript and enjoy the points from upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that the positions never change the code is:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
FOR /f "skip=1 tokens=5 delims=:," %%I IN (vers.json) DO IF NOT DEFINED ver SET "ver=%%I"
set ver=%ver:"=%
set ver=%ver: =%
echo !ver!
```

Answer (score 0):

Very easy for [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html):

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('xidel -s myFile.json -e "ver:=$json/(stable)()/version" --output-format^=cmd') DO %%A
```